# RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR doesn't return the message

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms, raise

```
IF l_value = 'FALSE' THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20299, 'some error message');
END IF;
```

This is part of table trigger. It should return me a error number and message, but when alert pops out it returns only message number. No 'some error message'. Whats wrong

Comment: What database type are you using? MS SQL? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: The alert is rendered by a client.  So your problem is with the client.

Comment: If problem with a clien, from where I should start looking?

Comment: How would we know? You haven't told us what client you are using...

Comment: What client application are you using?  What application is causing the alert to "pop out"?  That is the application that is discarding the error message.

Comment: This 'IF' is in the table trigger. statement 'FALSE' is returned from different function in same trigger. The message is poping out in Oracle form, when activating trigger when deleting row. But message have only '-20299', but no text.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the name `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` is misleading for you. It will not pop up something onto your GUI. That you program yourself depending on what client you are using. Put you can use `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` to create your own SQL errors on which you act upon.

Example

```
-- a example table
create table mytest (col_a number, col_b char(20));

-- a example trigger
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mytest_before
BEFORE UPDATE
    ON mytest
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    if :new.col_a < 0 then
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20299, 'negative value not allowed for column A');
    end if;
END;

insert into mytest values (1,'hallo');

set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  negative_value EXCEPTION; -- declare exception
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (negative_value, -20299); -- assign error code to exception
BEGIN
  update mytest set col_a = -1 where col_b = 'hallo';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN negative_value THEN -- handle exception
    -- do whatever you need to do to bring the error to the user
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(SQLERRM(-20299)));
END;
/
```

The above will bring you the output in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer of that sort.

```
table MYTEST created.
TRIGGER mytest_before compiled
1 rows inserted.
anonymous block completed
ORA-20299: negative value not allowed for column A
ORA-06512: at "DEMO.MYTEST_BEFORE", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DEMO.MYTEST_BEFORE
```

Instead of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE you can do whatever you need to do to show the user whatever you want him to show.

Answer (score 2):

The alert in your form has been raised by some trigger code on your form. Have a look at your `ON-ERROR` trigger - what code does it have?

You may need to augment it to show `DBMS_ERROR_TEXT` in the alert.